# addEventListener with "synchronization" event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to synchronize the context of two elements. Now I use `addEventListener("change",fun)` to abstract context from one element to another. However, this action is not real-time synchronization. We need to click the mouse at somewhere (or other action) so that the change is detected. Is that any real-time method?

Comment: did you see dispatchEvent considerations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is an input, you could use oninput:

```
element.addEventListener("input", fun);
```